# How to prevent my ISP or any third party from knowing my browsing history and such without VPN or DNS servers?

Tags: encryption, privacy, isp

Is it possible to encrypt my data before sending it through my ISP so all they see is an encrypted stream of what I am doing? How will that be possible? This should be done without using VPN, Tor, i2p, proxies, sshing into another server or similar.

Most preferably locally on my machine, but if there are other alternatives too, please make me aware of them.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. For some unknown reason you explicitly exclude established methods for privacy protection. These methods do not exist to make things more complicate  but because it is not possible to do only something on the local system and have all communication to other systems be magically protected.

Comment: If you encrypt something, the receiver needs to be able to decrypt it. Or have an intermediary decrypt it before it reaches the receiver. You can't do all that on only one end of the communication channel.

Comment: What does without DNS servers mean? That you will have to use the DNS server your ISP provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity sake, lets break your question into 2 questions:

> How to prevent my isp or any third party from knowing my browsing
>   history?

Multiple tools have been created to accomplish this:

- [vpn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN)
- [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)
- [tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network))
- [shadowsocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowsocks)
- [i2p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P)
- [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)
- [ICMP Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel)
- [Iodine](https://github.com/yarrick/iodine)
- [IPoAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)

> How do I do this with out any of the tools that would make this
>   possible?

[image]